# Use Geokettle to Transform file geodatabase data

Tags: file-geodatabase, ogr, geokettle

I would like to use GeoKettle to transform my file geodatabase data into something else (most likely postgis).  Admittedly I am very new to ETL but I am absolutely stumped when I try to define an input as file geodatabase.  "ogrinfo --formats" list file geodatabase as an option.

The reason I want to use the ETL is my long term solution will have to do with some schema changes (field names and probably types ) and with that mapping attributes to the new layer.

All of that is fine and good except I can't get out of the gate with using a file geodatabase as my input.

Ubuntu 14.04

Geokettle 2.5

[image: OGR input ScreenShot]

Comment: Are you able to read the file geodatabase in any other software on your PC, for example have you tried with QGIS?

Comment: ogr2ogr can read file geodatabases created in ArcGIS 10.0 onwards.

Comment: It's no problem reading the database.  That wasn't the question.  The question is in using file geodatabase as input/out in ETL actions from GeoKettle.  For example I use PostGIS to store 99% of my data, but I have requirements to deliver products in filegeodatabase format.  I need an ETL to convert from postgis to filegeodatabase with specific schema requirements.  So reading the gdb no problem, using it in GeoKettle ..can't seem to find out how.

Answer (score 3):

The FileGDB driver for ogr is disabled by default in geokettle (2.5). See the source at org/pentaho/di/core/geospatial/OGRReader.java:43:

```
private String[] unsupportedDrivers = { "FileGDB", "PostgresSQL/PostGIS", "IDB", "INGRES", "OCI", "MSSQLSpatial" };
```

I removed FileGDB from the list, recompiled that class, injected it into the jar, and all seems to work, albeit somewhat sluggishly. The sluggishness is due to geokettle's automatic re-querying of the schema of the input file to auto-fill various fields, coupled with the overhead involved in opening fgdb. You can bypass that by assigning the input file path to a variable or parameter, if you can live without the autocomplete.

This is why I love open source software. If it does not work now, it can be made to work, given enough effort.